# go routine panics when i return multiple errors

Tags: go, channel

I am playing around with worker pools and i want to consolidate all errors from worker pools before i return the error. I've written a sample code but i am entering a deadlock.

What am i trying to achieve?
a client send 100 requests,i want to first add those requests to a job queue and dispatch it to n number of go routines that does tasks in background , if at all there are errors i want to accumulate all these errors before i send all errors to the client. I have written a snippet, can someone explain what's wrong and how to mitigate the deadlock.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"

    "github.com/apex/log"
    "github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror"
)

type Manager struct {
    taskChan    chan int
    wg          *sync.WaitGroup
    QuitChan    chan bool
    ErrorChan   chan error
    busyWorkers int64
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    m := New()

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    //defer cancel()
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        m.wg.Add(1)
        go m.run(ctx, test)
    }

    for i := 1; i < 5; i++ {
        m.taskChan <- i
    }
    close(m.taskChan)
    go func(*Manager) {
        if len(m.taskChan) == 0 {
            m.QuitChan <- true
        }
    }(m)

    var errors error
    for {
        select {
        case err := <-m.ErrorChan:
            errors = multierror.Append(errors, err)
            if m.busyWorkers == int64(0) {
                break
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println("hello")
        }
    }
    m.wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(errors)

}
func New() *Manager {
    return &Manager{taskChan: make(chan int),
        wg:        new(sync.WaitGroup),
        QuitChan:  make(chan bool),
        ErrorChan: make(chan error),
    }
}

func (m *Manager) run(ctx context.Context, fn func(a, b int) error) {
    defer m.wg.Done()
    defer fmt.Println("finished working")
    for {
        select {
        case t, ok := <-m.taskChan:
            if ok {
                atomic.AddInt64(&m.busyWorkers, 1)
                err := fn(t, t)
                if err != nil {

                    m.ErrorChan <- err
                }
                atomic.AddInt64(&m.busyWorkers, -1)
            }

        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Infof("closing channel %v", ctx.Err())
            return
        case <-m.QuitChan:

            return
        }

    }
}
   // this can return error or not, this is the main driver func, but i'm propagating 
    //errors so that i can understand where i am going wrong
func test(a, b int) error {
    fmt.Println(a, b)
    return fmt.Errorf("dummy error %v", a)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 workers who all return errors.

Your main thread tries to put 5 jobs in the queue. Once the first 3 has been taken by your workers, the main thread is stuck waiting for a new worker to receive on `taskChan` and all your 3 workers are stuck trying to send data on `ErrorChan`.

In other words, deadlock.

Maybe you wanted to make `taskChan` a buffered channel? That way you can send data on it until the buffer is full without blocking.

```
taskChan: make(chan int, 10)
```

Comment: i actually don't know how many tasks and how many errors i will receive.

Comment: You asked what's wrong. I gave you a clear explanation.